# Terms of service error for verified user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I get the following error while trying to create Custom Audience from FB UserIds

> (OAuthException - #2655) (#2655) Terms of service has not been accepted

I asked the owner user of this ad account to Accept the terms of service in this link:
https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/customaudiences/tos.php

But he told me that he already accepted it. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The user whose access token you're using needs to accept the terms; maybe your client accepted the previous version of the terms and they've been updated subsequently?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 sets of custom audience Terms of Service:

- [Terms For Conversion Tracking, Custom Audiences From Your Website,
  and Custom Audiences From Your Mobile App](https://www.facebook.com/customaudiences/app/tos/)
- [Custom Audiences Terms](https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/customaudiences/tos.php)

Your user needs to accept both it sounds like. The error message from Facebook *should* have the correct URL to the un-accepted Terms of Service, but you should forward them both to your user just in case.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround right now is to accept the Terms of Service for Custom Audiences for all the available categories, even if you just upload dummy data in all of them.

Comment: Just for the record: The checkbox for the ToS is "hidden" in a modal dialog when creating a custom audience in the [audience manager](https://business.facebook.com/ads/audience_manager/)